# Do H dependent visa holders have due date that they have to enter the USA?

Tags: us-visa

I applied for an H1B US visa and I have a wife and children who will hopefully get dependent visas. My visa should be approved by USCIS in a few weeks, then I will need to go for an interview at the embassy. If I pass an interview successfully, I will move to the USA.

My kids study at school in my home city and therefore they are not ready to move to the USA right now. They are planning to accompany me in summer 2023.

My question is, if they get dependent visas now, can they join me next year? Or will they have the due date that they have to enter the USA? I couldn't find any useful information on the internet. Any information regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

They can enter on their H4 visa at any time on or before the visa's expiration date.

Comment: Thanks for your response @user102008